# How do I decrease the page size in nextjs and react app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, babeljs, next.js

[image]

in the above image you can see that the size of the dashboard.js is about 10.2 MB is surely not a normal case I do have minfied my code but page size still such large . Can anyone suggest me how I reduce the size of the page .

Answer (score 0):

Probably needs more information but confirm that you are running the application in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check these analyzers:

- [with-webpack-bundle-size-analyzer](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-webpack-bundle-size-analyzer)
- [with-webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-webpack-bundle-analyzer)